# Chi square test negative difference

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, f-test

I am currently running a chi square test and my values from the hypothesised model are
65.387 on 24 df and I want to compare the results to another nested model which values are 28.535 on 8 df (28.535-65.387 =-36.852). However, my chi square difference is negative. Does this mean I cant run the test ? It is handwritten math I am using to obtain the chi square difference. I have got the numbers through a confirmatory factor analysis in AMOS, which has given me the two chi square values and the degrees of freedom.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How exactly are you running the test? For instance, if you have code implementing the test or handwritten math that you can type on here, please do post!

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have added to above question

Comment: You haven't added enough. What are two models you are comparing (write the model formulas). Are you trying to do the likelihood ratio test?